# Positioning image inside an image in React-Native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I want to position an image on top of another image but it should not to be affected from the parent images "contain" parameter. If i remove the resizeMode="contain" , it works fine but otherwise, it looks like this:
[image]

What i want to is, place the small image INSIDE the parent image. I actually want to place the small image to the exact corners. Not on the empty space due to resizeMode="contain". My code looks like this:

```
<PagerView style={styles.pager} initialPage={0} showPageIndicator>
    <View style={styles.picView} key={i}>
      <ImageBackground
        resizeMode="contain"
        style={styles.pic}
        source={{
          uri: post.contents[i].path,
        }}
      >
        <Image
          style={{ position: "absolute", height: 100, width: 100 }}
          source={{
            uri: post.contents[i].path,
          }}
        />
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  </PagerView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you , I had to do also something similar so I used like this and it worked for me.

```
<PagerView style={styles.pager} initialPage={0} showPageIndicator>
    <View style={styles.container} key={i}>
      <ImageBackground
        resizeMode="contain"
        style={styles.pic}
        source={{
          uri: post.contents[i].path,
        }}
      >
     <View style={styles.container1}>
        <Image
          style={styles.image}
          source={{
            uri: post.contents[i].path,
          }}
        />
    </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  </PagerView>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
container1: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
 
  pic: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
  },

  
});
```

Comment: Which component use container1 style? I think you missed something

Comment: It doesn't work, small image doesn't show up because you haven't give any dimensions to "image" style. When i give it width and height  properties and position: absolute, it still position itself to the empty space